# Can someone explain why all of my divs overlap each other?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

All of my divs overlap each other, but when I set the wrapper to be 150vh `min-height`, `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between` it works. But feel like this is bad code practices, since it can be unstable when I going to expand the code. When I try to add padding, it doesn't behave as normal.

All the divs automatic overlaps. I wondering why this is the case?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 150vh;
}

.main_box {
  grid-gap: 2em;
}

img {
  z-index: -1;
  max-height: 500px;
  min-width: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.grid_box {
  max-width: 600px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  padding: 2em;
}

.box {
  grid-column: col 3 / span 2;
  grid-row: row 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr;
}

svg {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.box_text {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main_box">
    <img class="image_box" src="https://jobzone.no/globalassets/kontorbilder/bergen.jpg" );/>
    <div class="grid_box">
      <div class="box">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="76" height="76" viewBox="0 0 76 76">
                                    <g id="Group_66" data-name="Group 66" transform="translate(-3 76) rotate(-90)">
                                    <rect id="Rectangle_1185" data-name="Rectangle 1185" width="30" height="20" transform="translate(0 31)" fill="#191923"/>
                                    <rect id="Rectangle_1186" data-name="Rectangle 1186" width="20" height="20" transform="translate(28 31)" fill="#191923"/>
                                    <rect id="Rectangle_1187" data-name="Rectangle 1187" width="28" height="20" transform="translate(48 31)" fill="#f4b54e"/>
                                    <rect id="Rectangle_1188" data-name="Rectangle 1188" width="20" height="30" transform="translate(28 3)" fill="#191923"/>
                                    <rect id="Rectangle_1189" data-name="Rectangle 1189" width="20" height="30" transform="translate(28 49)" fill="#191923"/>
                                    </g>
                                </svg>
        <div class="box_text">
          <h2>1 Helhetlig utforming</h2>
          <p>
            Denne eksempelsamlingen viser prosjekter som bygger opp under målsettingen om en vakker, særpreget, inkluderende og grønn by, og forankres i ett.
          </p>
          <a href="#">Vis mer</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="main_box">
    <img class="image_box" src="https://jobzone.no/globalassets/kontorbilder/bergen.jpg" );/>
    <div class="grid_box">
      <div class="box">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="76" height="76" viewBox="0 0 76 76">
                                    <g id="Group_66" data-name="Group 66" transform="translate(-3 76) rotate(-90)">
                                    <rect id="Rectangle_1185" data-name="Rectangle 1185" width="30" height="20" transform="translate(0 31)" fill="#191923"/>
                                    <rect id="Rectangle_1186" data-name="Rectangle 1186" width="20" height="20" transform="translate(28 31)" fill="#191923"/>
                                    <rect id="Rectangle_1187" data-name="Rectangle 1187" width="28" height="20" transform="translate(48 31)" fill="#f4b54e"/>
                                    <rect id="Rectangle_1188" data-name="Rectangle 1188" width="20" height="30" transform="translate(28 3)" fill="#191923"/>
                                    <rect id="Rectangle_1189" data-name="Rectangle 1189" width="20" height="30" transform="translate(28 49)" fill="#191923"/>
                                    </g>
                            </svg>
        <div class="box_text">
          <h2>2 Helhetlig utforming</h2>
          <p>
            Denne eksempelsamlingen viser prosjekter som bygger opp under målsettingen om en vakker, særpreget, inkluderende og grønn by, og forankres i ett.
          </p>
          <a href="#">Vis mer</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="main_box">
    <img class="image_box" src="https://jobzone.no/globalassets/kontorbilder/bergen.jpg" );/>
    <div class="grid_box">
      <div class="box">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="76" height="76" viewBox="0 0 76 76">
                                <g id="Group_66" data-name="Group 66" transform="translate(-3 76) rotate(-90)">
                                <rect id="Rectangle_1185" data-name="Rectangle 1185" width="30" height="20" transform="translate(0 31)" fill="#191923"/>
                                <rect id="Rectangle_1186" data-name="Rectangle 1186" width="20" height="20" transform="translate(28 31)" fill="#191923"/>
                                <rect id="Rectangle_1187" data-name="Rectangle 1187" width="28" height="20" transform="translate(48 31)" fill="#f4b54e"/>
                                <rect id="Rectangle_1188" data-name="Rectangle 1188" width="20" height="30" transform="translate(28 3)" fill="#191923"/>
                                <rect id="Rectangle_1189" data-name="Rectangle 1189" width="20" height="30" transform="translate(28 49)" fill="#191923"/>
                                </g>
                            </svg>
        <div class="box_text">
          <h2>3 Helhetlig utforming</h2>
          <p>
            Denne eksempelsamlingen viser prosjekter som bygger opp under målsettingen om en vakker, særpreget, inkluderende og grønn by, og forankres i ett.
          </p>
          <a href="#">Vis mer</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="main_box">
    <img class="image_box" src="https://jobzone.no/globalassets/kontorbilder/bergen.jpg" );/>
    <div class="grid_box">
      <div class="box">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="76" height="76" viewBox="0 0 76 76">
                                <g id="Group_66" data-name="Group 66" transform="translate(-3 76) rotate(-90)">
                                <rect id="Rectangle_1185" data-name="Rectangle 1185" width="30" height="20" transform="translate(0 31)" fill="#191923"/>
                                <rect id="Rectangle_1186" data-name="Rectangle 1186" width="20" height="20" transform="translate(28 31)" fill="#191923"/>
                                <rect id="Rectangle_1187" data-name="Rectangle 1187" width="28" height="20" transform="translate(48 31)" fill="#f4b54e"/>
                                <rect id="Rectangle_1188" data-name="Rectangle 1188" width="20" height="30" transform="translate(28 3)" fill="#191923"/>
                                <rect id="Rectangle_1189" data-name="Rectangle 1189" width="20" height="30" transform="translate(28 49)" fill="#191923"/>
                                </g>
                            </svg>
        <div class="box_text">
          <h2>4 Helhetlig utforming</h2>
          <p>
            Denne eksempelsamlingen viser prosjekter som bygger opp under målsettingen om en vakker, særpreget, inkluderende og grønn by, og forankres i ett.
          </p>
          <a href="#">Vis mer</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You have the images set to `position: absolute`. Then you set the `left` offset, but since you haven't set `top` or `bottom`, or extra space (`height`) in the container, they overlap. Once you give the container extra space (`min-height: 150vh`), the elements have room to expand.

Comment: Also `grid-gap` applies to the container, not the items.

Comment: Thank you, know I understand.